# Changing symbology from simple marker into a vector (print of a building)

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, vector, markers

I've got a question about changing the symbology of a certain rule-based layer. See below as to the current simple marker:
[image: Simple red marker]

As you can see the house is given this grey color because of the added 'topo' vector layer. The question I have now is, is it possible for me to make the red marker into the vector: I want the whole building to be red. I tried the different symbology settings (raster image, vector field marker etc.) but no luck. It is also (in my understanding) not possible for the vector layer to be rule based because it does not contain the information to be filtered. Maybe combine the vector layer within the other layer that contains the rules?

I can answer the follow-up questions.

Comment: Although the vector layer does not contain any information to be filtered in its attribute table, it is possible the vector layer to be rule based using geometric properties of features (perimeter, area for polygons; length, azimuth for lines).

Answer (score 0):

all layers except the "Red" layer are raster layers. so it is not possible to simply change the color of the building

Comment: Okay, so what would be the way this is possible? Is it possible for the vector layer to be integrated to the 'red' data source?

Comment: red is vector layer @Jan. You'd need the geometry information in order to display it.

Comment: Yeah so the geometry information I do have (lon, lat) from the red simple markers.

Comment: you'd need the geometry information of the whole building (all vertex points of that building), ergo a polygon. this polygon would be possible to color in whatever fashion you want. but as your building is only there in the raster layer, this is not possible. you would need to digitze the building manually into your vector(polygon)layer

Comment: Okay so the polygon data is imported via a featureserver. The red dots (lon, lat) are imported via delimited text layer. I understand it is not possible to get the featureserver data into the delimited text, right? It is also not possible to do anything with the data from the featureserver because I don't manage it. It's also not possible to change the symbology to get what I need? Sorry for the (vague) questions, I still find this a bit hard.

Comment: if the spatial extend is "managable" (depends somewhat on your internet connection) you can try and download the building polygons from OSM (relatively easy with the QGIS plugin "QuickOSM") - then you would have the buildings as vector data and can style it the way you want

Comment: Because the buildings layer is a feature service, it is just displayed on the screen. You cannot edit it if the owner of that feature service has not given you permission to do that. As @sn1ks said, you need to either have editing permissions or you could download the buildings from QuickOSM so they would be your 'own' copy of this dataset which you can style any way you like